# How to assign a hostname on the Internet side of a MikroTik

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik-routeros

I am using a MikroTik Router as a security gateway to isolate devices that have no DHCP nor hostname configuration from a company network that only uses DHCP.

Thus, I would like to associate a hostname to the Router in order to access the isolated devices (through NAT).

I am not familiar with the RouterOS and the SSH terminal is cumbersome (side question: is it possible to have a full root bash access?), I am far more familiar with netfilter...

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a hostname in your company network's DHCP system? (i.e. have ROS make registrations on behalf of each device?)

Comment: I would like to set the hostname in the router. The same way I configure /etc/hostname

Answer (score 2):

By default, the hostname used by the RouterOS DHCP client is read from `/system identity`.

```
/system identity set name=MyRouter
```

The "identity" name is, indeed just like /etc/hostname, also used for various other things besides DHCP – for example, it's what shows up in device discovery lists (LLDP, RoMON).

If you want to change the hostname *only* for DHCP lease requests while keeping the router's "identity" (e.g. ISP requires a specific name that doesn't suit your internal scheme), you can do that through `/ip dhcp-client option` by changing DHCP option `12`.

There you'll find a built-in item that sends the "identity" hostname. To customize it, it's best to create a completely new 'option' item, then assign it to the 'dhcp-client' item:

1. ```
   > /ip/dhcp-client/option

   > print
      #   NAME           CODE  VALUE               RAW-VALUE     
      2 * hostname         12  $(HOSTNAME)         456d6265724757

   > add name=CustomHostname code=12 value=foo
   ```
2. ```
   > /ip/dhcp-client

   > print detail
      0  interface=ether1 dhcp-options=hostname,clientid

   > set 0 dhcp-options=CustomHostname,clientid
   ```

No, there is no Linux shell access on RouterOS. It's an appliance OS that only happens to be based on a Linux kernel (and it does re-use the existing routing and Netfilter/iptables functionality), but there are none of the usual userspace tools present; every single daemon running on the system is fully custom.